# Syntax Error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxt.js and I'm getting this error

> Syntax Error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'

this is the code

```
<template>
  <div class="mt-6">loggedInUser: {{ loggedInUser }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  middleware: 'auth',
  async fetch() {
    await this.$auth
      .fetchUser()
      .then((response) => (this.loggedInUser = response.data.data))
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loggedInUser: this.$auth.user.data,
    }
  },

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are exporting an object. an object has key value pairs.

You have not defined key for **async fetch()** and for **data**

consider doing it like this.

```
export default {
  middleware: 'auth',
  fetch: async () => {
    await this.$auth
      .fetchUser()
      .then((response) => (this.loggedInUser = response.data.data))
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      loggedInUser: this.$auth.user.data,
    }
  },

}
```

Comment: It will fail because you replaced it with an arrow and `this` is useless in this context. `async fetch() {` is perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: @Mansoor thanks I tried it but unfortunately it failed

Comment: in that case you need to bind the function with this.
for example: const fetch = (() => {}).bind(this)
this would work because now this would reference the desired object in your case.

Comment: @Mansoor for some reason your posted answer works now

Comment: `const fetch = (() => {}).bind(this)` - this is a mistake. Arrows don't have `bind` method, that's the whole idea behind them.

Comment: @AIB The answer is incorrect. `this` refers to module object there, so it can share data between multiple users on server side. It's not supposed to be workable because `this.$auth` doesn't exist. If it's working for you, it's possibly because the application doesn't reflect the current state of code, because of cache or else.

Comment: @ Estus Flask  I refreshed the cache and now when I run the code I'm getting "Cannot read property '$auth' of undefined", do you have a suggestion what a better solution would be?

Comment: @AIB I have no solution because the problem is not well-defined. The code you posted is the way this needs to be done. It cannot cause `Unexpected reserved word 'await'` error because it uses `await` inside `async`, and this is enough for the syntax to be correct. If you had problems with caching, it's likely that some old code was cached and caused the error too.